# Browser inside a web page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, browser

I want to build a website that function as a "broswer", meaning displays website (such as facebook, google, yahoo...). It has a url bar, where the user inputs the address he want to visit, and a window where the content will be presented. the "web page browser" will be access through any browser (chrome, IE, firefox...) as a normal web page (that displays other websites).

My question are:

1. does such a thing already exist?
2. how can I build such a thing? meaning which technologies or programming languages I should use (JS? AJEX?)

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at any online proxy or at google translate (when it translates sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building such a system should really be pretty elementary.

**Q: Does such a thing already exist?**

*Indeed* there are similar systems (online proxies, e.t.c.) although I can't see any value at all in creating such a 'browser'

**Q: How would I go implementing such an 'inline browser'?**

*Please don't try doing this via Javascript, You'll end up with a really messy and unpractical solution.*

In other words, I'd recommend using one of some popular scripting languages:

- PHP
- Perl
- Python

And others, just google 'server-side scripting languages' or something along those lines.

Concerning implementation, I'd do something like the following (step list):

1. Download the HTML source of the page via an AJAX, Javascript, PHP, whatever.
2. Once downloaded, you place the HTML source into an iframe/div located on your 'browser' page
3. You can let the user interact with it as he/she wishes.

Another approach would be to simply modify the **src** property of an iframe.

Read on iframes and how to use them : [iframe tag - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: And by the way, if you download the HTML on the server side, instead of the client side, you can build in interesting features like: proxy connections, advertisements (for users), e.t.c.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not trying to build an inline browser just for the sake of it - it is the first step in building a interactive browser where users will be able to see which other users are on the same sites as them.

Comment: @user1007665, Interesting.. By the way, some websites might block you if you don't supply a valid 'User Agent' (google 'change user agent in php'). Another thing you should also look at for is usage of your browser for malicious purposes, which might also get you blocked in a lot of places (Google for instance).